# I have a table with uuid and system column. I need a query to return only uuid's having system=1 but not the uuids with system= 1 nad 2

Tags: mysql

I have a table with uuid and system column. I need a query to return only uuid's having system=1 but not the uuids with system= 1 and 2

Comment: Please paste the DDL table definition.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable m
WHERE   system = 1
        AND NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.uuid = m.uuid
                AND mi.system = 2
        )
```

Comment: The case is just an example. I will have more system types not just 1 and 2. Also I need a way to find uuid with say 1,2,3 and 3,4,5, 3 being the common value